# Shell script to cd and ls automatically on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script

I'm running macOS Sierra and attempting to write a shell script that will allow me to use one command to `cd` and `ls` at the same time. [I am going off of this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20396/make-cd-automatically-ls), but have had no luck adapting it to my script.

The directory: `/usr/local/bin/`

The file name: `cdls`

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cdls() { builtin cd "$@" && ls; }
```

I have never written a shell script besides a simple `echo hello world` file, so if you could point me in the right direction it would be awesome. Thanks.

EDIT: `/usr/local/bin` is in my `PATH`

Comment: Like others said in the thread, you just need to add the function `cdls()` to your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would accomplish this by typing the following in the terminal:

```
. cdls /usr/local/bin/
```

Where `cdls` is a bash script stored in my `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
ls
```

The `.` in the terminal command sources the script, rather than using a subshell.

The `$1` in the bash script takes `usr/local/bin/` (defined in the command line) as an argument.

You could replace `$1` with any other directory in the script if you always wanted to `cdls` to a certain directory.

As far as the other question you referenced. The top answer recommends this:

```
cdls() { cd "$@" && ls; }
```

which is a function and should be inserted into your `.bash_profile` (for macOS) or `.bashrc` (for Linux), rather than be used in a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

The example you got from that thead is for the creation of bash function that you would put in your `.profile`.  If you wanted to create a script instead instead of adding a function to your profile your script would need to look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
builtin cd "$@" && ls
```

Comment: This is what I had at one point, however, it only executes the `ls` portion and it does not `cd` into the directory.

Comment: @Jay The script version actually does `cd` to the directory, but since it's a script it executes in a subshell -- it's only the subshell that changes directory, there's no way for it to affect the parent shell (i.e. *your* shell). That's why it has to be a function instead of a script.

Comment: yes, it changed dir for following commands but it does not show the new dir when the command runs so it might be confusing